# Whats better to set bitmap in xml or programmatically in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, error-handling

Which is the better way to set a `Bitmap`, setting it in xml as background or setting it programmatically?

I'm encountering `Out of Memory` issue and sometime giving binary xml error.I have used  background image of max size 500kb(xxhdpi). So I'm wondering which is the better way to set bitmap as background.

Setting bitmap in xml or setting it in programmatically in java class.

Does anyone have say about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: XML is better. Programmatically is slow

Comment: `I have used an background image of 500kb.` <= size doesnt matter what matters is a resolution

Comment: So it will not cause out of memory exception if image is heavy?

Comment: remeber that the bitmap object created from image will take W*H*4 bytes ... for ARGB_8888 ... so image with 4k resolution will take 35MB

Comment: @Selvin, Resolution is 960*1,440(xxhdpi). For hdpi its 480*720.

Comment: 5,5 MB ... so you should not have memory issue at least at first Activity launch ... maybe you have some Activity leak problem

Comment: @Selvin, ya its not at first activity launch, its second or third time, or sometimes after a long time when I launch that activity again.

Comment: @Selvin, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it in xml as background or setting it programmatically do no differences on memory Occupation.
In my project,I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) managing internet pictures and local pictures.
Image frame such as Glide is helpful for out of memory issue.

It has many details.

1.Set DecodeFormat to "PREFER_RGB_565".

2.Propositional set target image with and height in ViewTarget.

3.Using jpg drawable instead of png drawable if allowed.

Any questions please add a comment.

Comment: I want to ask that as you say Glide manages pictures, but if my image is on xml so if it is causing out of memory error, so what can be done for that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can manage local image by Glide too.Focus on Glide.with(this).load() function, u can set local drawable xml such as 'R.drawable.a'.    In that way,Glide manager all drawable in your app(both local and net) by its Lru-cache.When memory is not enough,Glide can recycle old drawables avoid   OOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to set bitmap with [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) in programmatically to avoid encountering Out of Memory.

And,there may be not a good way to deal with OOM in xml directly.